# Can I draw shapes over an svg file

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I need to draw shapes like rectangle,circle etc dynamically over an existing svg. ie when i click on the svg it should select and highlight the particular path in the svg. Then i want draw shapes on the highlighted area. How to achieve this?

Comment: whats your actual need? u need to highlight the selected shape?

Comment: I need draw new shapes on highlighted area of existing svg

Comment: can you please post your code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

To draw on the SVG :

```
var svg_ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var my_svg = document.getElementById('your_svg');

var new_shape = document.createElementNS(svg_ns, 'rect');
new_shape.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
new_shape.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);
new_shape.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '50');
new_shape.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '50');
new_shape.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill','#00FF00');
my_svg.appendChild(new_shape);
```

To get SVG Path's :

```
var svg_paths = my_svg.getElementsByTagName("path");
/* Then to hightlight a path : svg_paths[i].stroke='#0000FF' */
```

You can view basic shapes information on :
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html

Comment: Can I draw a new shape over the selected path, ie i need the highlighted area as background and on the top of that svg background i want to draw new shapes.Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, many operations are needed, eg. drawing rectangles in SVG is rather complicated. Let me explain: It is easy to highlight (or colorize) element by clicking and add a new element below cursor, but "drawing element" usually needs some sort of "resize by dragging" and it is a little more complicated. Using some library could help a lot: eg.

- http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/ (Click Simple to draw rectangles etc)
- http://raphaeljs.com/ if you want a little more "raw" approach.
- http://demos.bonsaijs.org/demos/draggable-shapes/index.html

Comment: Thanks! Added it. Bonsai also has an excellent getBoundingBox() function, which I have not found bugs yet. Raphael has similar, but it fails in some cases. And Raphael has rather big amount of unfixed bugs: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues?labels=bug&page=1&state=open, of which some are three years old.